# Vaadin - Remove Component from its parent

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

In the Vaadin framework (v7.1.9), how do we remove a `Component` from it's parent?

I'm only aware of the `removeComponent` function, but that requires me to get a handle on the parent (ugly):

```
ComponentContainer parent = (ComponentContainer) child.getParent();
parent.removeComponent(child);
```

I tried to just `detach` the child but that removed it from the 'application' without removing the `Component` from the UI.

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Comment: Why do you think this is ugly? It is like removing an Element from a Collection (`HashSet`, `ArrayList`...).

Comment: Ok, I like the HashSet/ArrayList comparison. However, when working with `HashSet` or `ArrayList`, you don't need to cast. `remove` is defined in `Collection`. In Vaadin, `removeComponent` is defined in `ComponentContainer`.. but `Component.getParent()` returns a `HasComponents` object instead. To me, this is either a flaw in the API or this isn't the way to do what I want to do. What do you guys think?

Comment: honestly I didn't check the interfaces, but it's a good point. I think the reason for this is that some parents are implementing `SingleComponentContainer` and not `HasComponents`. `Panel` for example. But I'm not working on vaadin only using it. May I ask you in what situation you have a component and don't know its parent?

Comment: In Java collection comparison how would you get parent collection for a child element? It's totally different situation. I think you should remove components inside your layout class where you will just call `removeComponent` method without any casts

Answer (score 4):

if Child is added to Any Layout you should cast it to that layout e.g if child ws added to AbsoluteLayout then

```
AbsoluteLayout parent = (AbsoluteLayout ) child.getParent();
parent.removeComponent(child);
```

Try this one

Comment: If this Ans Solve your problem then please select it as ANS

Answer (score 3):

Or like this if child was added to layout.

```
Layout parent = ( Layout ) child.getParent();
parent.removeComponent(child)
```

I think this is better than Mubasher solution because it's implementation independent, I mean you don't have to know the Parent layout and if it changes the code still works.

Comment: My original code is better for the same reason. `ComponentContainer` is the lowest interface and is what specifies `removeComponent`, so it's the most robust cast. Still, I've decided it's a Vaadin API flaw that the cast is needed at all. That's the real answer =\